# "projective activity" in cognitive sciences context [RESOLVED]

Tags: meaning-in-context, psychology

I<strike>'m</strike> was not sure what is meant by projective in this context.

> As in the case of understanding spoken or written language, an enormous
>   amount of general knowledge is constantly mobilized in service of
>   this projective activity, which freely utilizes any and all relevant sensory
>   data available to it. (*The Irreducible Mind*, Kelly, et al, p.40)

As I explained in comment, just the previous para. makes clear what "projective activity" means. That's the process of our mind "projecting" its past models on sensory data to recognize them without having to pay attention to all the details. I quote the previous para. here:

> A separate tradition dating back at least to Kant and the early Gestalt
>   theorists, and carried forward into the modern era by psychologists such
>   as Neisser (1 967, 1 976), has been sensitive to the presence of "top-down"
>   influences, both within and between sensory modalities. Although a few
>   perceptual subsystems (such as those that engender the Miiller-Lyer and
>   other incorrigible visual illusions) may be truly autonomous or "cognitively
>   impenetrable" in the sense of J. Fodor ( 1983), these seem to be isolated and
>   special cases. A very different overall picture of perceptual synthesis is currently
>   emerging in which top-down influences predominate. On this view
>   40Chapter 1
>   perceptual synthesis is achieved not from the input, but with its aid. This is
>   necessarily the case for example in regard to ambiguous figures, where the
>   stimulus information itself is not sufficient to determine a uniquely "correct"
>   interpretation. More generally, we routinely ignore information that
>   is present in the input and supply information that is not, speed-reading
>   providing a characteristic example.29 Something within us, a sort of cosmogenic,
>   world-generating, or virtual-reality system, is continuously updating
>   and projecting an overall model of the perceptual environment and our position
>   within it, guided by very limited samplings of the available sensory
>   information (Simons & Chabris, 1999; Tart, 1993).

Comment: A projective test in psychology is something like ink blot tests or thematic apperception test, which is basically looking at a picture and making up a narrative about it. I think it's also done in writing by completing sentences. It's kind of like "say what comes in your mind" type of thing that supposedly reveals something about you, or your unconscious side. Not sure if that fits the meaning in your book. Also, a search revealed that this exact question has been asked at least twice before, on other sites, from the same book. Edit: actually, both of those links link to this question, weird.

Comment: @Zebrafish, Thank you but I looking again at the context, I just understood what is meant by this phrase. The projective activity is actually explained in the immediately previous paragraph of the book, but since that was exactly where I stopped reading yesterday I had forgotten the context when I started from the next para. today. And interesting if the 'Irreducible Mind' is attracting questions here. I feel more comfortable asking more in future about this ground-breaking book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I surmised, it's referring to what in psychology are referred to as projective tests. Here is the Wikipedia article to it if you want to know all about it. [Link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_test)

In a nutshell, projective tests present a subject with ambiguous stimuli, and a person is encouraged to tell the therapist or experimenter what has come to mind, or sometimes they are shown pictures and told to make up a story. The point of this is to try (not sure how successful it is) to get an idea of either unconscious processes or thoughts, or to understand a person's prior experiences.

Examples of these tests are ones like the ink blot tests, like [Rorschach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_test), [Draw a Person Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draw-a-Person_test), [Sentence completion tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_completion_tests), and [Thematic Apperception Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_apperception_test). The final one listed actually includes the word that psychologists and philosophers use, to apperceive.

> 1. to be aware of perceiving
> 2. (Psychology) psychol to comprehend by assimilating (a perception) to ideas already in the mind
>     [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/apperceive)

To give just a basic layman's explanation, as I am very lay, a person is said to perceive a stimulus. To say that a person "apperceives" something is to say that that person is perceiving the stimulus in the normal sense, but taking into consideration the totality of prior life experience and the prism through which we view the world. That's to say that different people perceive the same objects and stimuli in different ways. That's the point, or the aim of these projective tests, to try to reveal something through these tasks where people are told to share what they perceive from an ambiguous thing.

You can tell this is what the author is referring to, because just before your excerpt they write:

> On this view perceptual synthesis is achieved not from the input, but
>   with its aid. This is necessarily the case for example in regard to
>   ambiguous figures, where the stimulus information is not sufficient to
>   determine a uniquely "correct" interpretation.

Comment: Thank you, again! Yes, even though this is not a test context, but the idea is the same.